# Always load startpoint (DIV-position) from given coordinates

Tags: javascript, jquery, coordinates

I am trying to create a game where you have to move a ball on a platform. At the start of the game, the ball is dropped on the platform and then you can move it around with the arrow keys. This is al working, no problems here.

The game starts with a ball dropped on a yellow tile as can be seen in [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mauricederegt/BKEbL/6/) (click the 1 to start). The platform is build in `javascript` as follows (for level 1 and 2):

```
var levels = [
    [
        [1,1,1,1,1],
        [1,1,1,1,1],
        [1,2,1,1,1]
    ],
    [
        [1,1,1,2,1],
        [1,1,1,1,1],
        [1,1,1,1,1]
    ]
];
```

Where 1 = green tile, 0 = no tile and 2 is a yellow tile.

To let the ball drop on the yellow tile, I have the following code:

```
go: function() {
            ball.reset((1*100+50),(2*100+50));
            start();
        }
```

Where `(1*100+50)` is the x-coordinate of the yellow tile and `(2*100+50)` the y. Better explained: 1 is 1 tile to the right * tile length + 50 ( +50 is to drop the ball in the middle of the div). All works as intended.

But if I load level 2 (see the fiddle, click the 2), we see that the yellow tile is moved, but the ball is still dropped at the fixed spot (see `go: function`). This is what I need to fix.

I want these yellow tile coordinates to be loaded when a level is loaded. In this case, the simplest thing to do is to add these coordinates with each level. I thought about something like this:

```
var levels = [
    {
        yellowTile : [1, 2],
             tiles : [ [1,1,1,1,1],
                       [1,1,1,1,1],
                       [1,2,1,1,1] ]
    },
    {
        yellowTile : [3, 0],
             tiles : [ [1,1,1,2,1],
                       [1,1,1,1,1],
                       [1,1,1,1,1] ]
    }
];
```

So the `go: function` will be like:

```
go: function() {
            ball.reset((yellowTileX*100+50),(yellowTileY*100+50));
            start();
        }
```

But I have no luck in making this work. Hope someone can help me out here.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to find the start position is to save it when looping all the tiles. I've modified your script so the start position is saved by adding the following to loadLevel:

```
    if(levels[level][i][j] === 2) {
        startPosition = {x: j, y: i};
    }
```

I've added the function getStartPosition() to the plane class, this function can be used in the 'go' function to fetch the start x and y of the plane. This can be used to reset the ball to the correct x and y

```
    go: function() {
        ball.reset((plane.getStartPosition().x*100+50),(plane.getStartPosition().y*100+50));
        start();
    }
```

Check out my modified version: http://jsfiddle.net/BKEbL/7/

Comment: Cool this is even easier then what I had in mind. Thanks a lot!